# JavaScript loop on span elements, checking their values and replacing other node border-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm in a process of making a new website on Wordpress CMS, and have quite a big problem down here.

What I would like to achieve? Well I'm implementing an review system, and with PHP I'm picking the custom taxonomy values in my website, pasting it as an circular chart. Everything is working correctly, but I would like to achieve one more effect. I would like to change the colour of circles based on taxonomy value (right now it's in the span element).

How am I suppose to achieve that? I tried a lot of diffrent JS/JQuery codes, but nothing worked properly (most of the time, It only picked 1st span value, and set up the colour for all elements, instead of checking all of them).

Here is one example of code:

HTML:

```
                            <div class="c100 p<?php $score = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'score' );
                                                               $score = strip_tags( $score );
                                                               echo $score;
                                                               ?>">
                              <span class="rate"><?php $score = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'score' );
                                                               $score = strip_tags( $score );
                                                               echo $score;
                                                               ?></span>
                              <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JS:

```
 var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('c100');
   for (i=0;i<=temp.length;i++) {
       var rate = document.getElementsByClassName('rate');
       if (parseInt(rate[i].innerHTML) < 25 ) {
           border = {'border-color':'red'};
           $('.pie, .c100 .bar, .c100.p51 .fill, .c100.p52 .fill, .c100.p53 .fill, .c100.p54 .fill, .c100.p55 .fill, .c100.p56 .fill, .c100.p57 .fill, .c100.p58 .fill, .c100.p59 .fill, .c100.p60 .fill, .c100.p61 .fill, .c100.p62 .fill, .c100.p63 .fill, .c100.p64 .fill, .c100.p65 .fill, .c100.p66 .fill, .c100.p67 .fill, .c100.p68 .fill, .c100.p69 .fill, .c100.p70 .fill, .c100.p71 .fill, .c100.p72 .fill, .c100.p73 .fill, .c100.p74 .fill, .c100.p75 .fill, .c100.p76 .fill, .c100.p77 .fill, .c100.p78 .fill, .c100.p79 .fill, .c100.p80 .fill, .c100.p81 .fill, .c100.p82 .fill, .c100.p83 .fill, .c100.p84 .fill, .c100.p85 .fill, .c100.p86 .fill, .c100.p87 .fill, .c100.p88 .fill, .c100.p89 .fill, .c100.p90 .fill, .c100.p91 .fill, .c100.p92 .fill, .c100.p93 .fill, .c100.p94 .fill, .c100.p95 .fill, .c100.p96 .fill, .c100.p97 .fill, .c100.p98 .fill, .c100.p99 .fill, .c100.p100 .fill').css(border);
       } else {
           border = {'border-color':'green'};
           console.log("nie ma tragedii");
       };
   }
```

So what I would like to achieve? 
1. Pick the amount of span elements of .span class
2. Make a loop of the amount picked in 1 step
3. Check the value of span nodes
4. If the value is less than 25, set border-color of some class to red
5. If the value is less than 50 but greater than 25 change to yellow
6. If the value is less than 75 but greater than 25 change to blue
7. If higher, set the colour to green

Thanks from the start and Cheers!

Comment: post your relevant html

Answer (score 0):

In your code `for (i=0;i<=temp.length;i++)` is wrong it should be `for (i=0;i<temp.length;i++)` otherwise it'll throw outofindex error.

Since I've no idea of your HTML. I've used 4 `span`s with different values and class as `span` in order to fulfill your requirement. I looped it using `$.each` function and retrieve their `text`. And then set their border color as per your conditions.

```js
$('.rate').each(function(){
  var val=parseInt($(this).text());
  $div=$(this).parent().find('.fill');
  if(val<=25){
    $div.css('border-color','red');
  }else if(val>25 && val<=50){
    $div.css('border-color','yellow');
  }else if(val>50 && val<=75){
    $div.css('border-color','blue');
  }
  else if(val>75){
    $div.css('border-color','green');
  }
});
```

```css
.fill{
  padding:10px;
  border-width:2px;
  border-style:solid;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reviews">
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/tbc.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:#3e0201">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p75">
                <span class="rate">75</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: TBC</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/wow-tbc/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 13 godzin ago</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/legion.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:green">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p98">
                <span class="rate">98</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: Legion</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/test-5/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 dzień ago                                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mop.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:black">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p50">
                <span class="rate">50</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: MoP</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/test-4/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 dzień ago                                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cata.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:red">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p5">
                <span class="rate">5</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: Cata</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/test-3/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 dzień ago                                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added HTML, however your code changed all borders to red

Comment: look at the snippet. They are different `red`,`yellow`,`blue`,`green`

Comment: I know :) Im just saying that on localhost it unfortunately changed all to red

Comment: And you've different value there? Can you get the real HTML( after php code is executed in the browser). I am not able to guess the real content

Comment: Posted, what is wrong? Is it because of PHP? But the JS is included in the footer, it should work fine.

Comment: Answer updated. Check the output. NOTE: Your elements are not uniform work on that

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by saying they are not uniform? Cheers

Comment: You've changed the background color of parent element, I need the code to change the border colors of .fill and .bar elements. Cheers

Comment: Updated. `.fill` css class is just to make it visible easily. you can ignore it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="reviews">
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/tbc.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:#3e0201">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p75">
                <span class="rate">75</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: TBC</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/wow-tbc/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 13 godzin ago</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/legion.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:green">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p98">
                <span class="rate">98</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: Legion</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/test-5/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 dzień ago                                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mop.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:black">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p50">
                <span class="rate">50</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: MoP</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/test-4/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 dzień ago                                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-review">
    <div class="thumb-bar">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="bg" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cata.jpg">
            <div class="thumb-tag">
                PC </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review" id="review" style="background:red">
            <p> score:</p>
            <div class="c100 p5">
                <span class="rate">5</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar" style="border-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="fill"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-note">
        <h3>WoW: Cata</h3>
        <div class="tag-list">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">
            <span class="game-tags"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/genre/rpg/" rel="tag">RPG</a>  </span>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada e... <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/reviews/test-3/">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="news-info">
            <div class="time-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 dzień ago                                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comments-stamp">
                <span>
                                    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/blog/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt="">0                                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rate').each(function(){
              var val=parseInt($(this).text());
              $div=$(this).parent().find('.bar');
              $divTwo=$(this).parent().find('.fill');
              if(val<=25){
                $div.css('border-color','red');
                  $divTwo.css('border-color','red');
              }else if(val>25 && val<=50){
                $div.css('border-color','yellow');
                  $divTwo.css('border-color','yellow');
              }else if(val>50 && val<=75){
                $div.css('border-color','blue');
                  $divTwo.css('border-color','blue');
              }else if(val>75){
                $div.css('border-color','green');
                  $divTwo.css('border-color','green');
              }
        });
```

Used this code and now it works as intented, really thanks for help. Now I understand what was the problem, wish you luck, cheers!